# Tomcat 7 not Displaying webapp, 403 Error

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a webapp under /webapps/ with a WebRoot folder within in it, so /webapps/APPNAME/WebRoot. Within WebRoot there is a WEB-INF folder with a web.xml file specifying the homepage should be index.jsp. I have added the alias to httpd.conf, but when I visit it i get a 403 forbidden, and the web.xml is not being loaded. (If i add an index.html file it will be loaded as the home page so the default web.xml is being used instead). Any ideas why the web.xml is not being loaded? Thanks!

Comment: You mention httpd.conf without any context of how you combine Apache httpd with tomcat. I'd like to suggest to try with pure Tomcat, no httpd. Get it to run there, then worry about httpd.

Comment: Your `WEB-INF` directory needs to be in `webapps/APPNAME` and not in `webapps/APPNAME/WebRoot`. How have you configured httpd to proxy to Tomcat?